# Is This the best way to use ternary operators?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

this is the best way to use ternary operator to check validation?

```
public void cadastrarUsuario (View view) {
    if (validacao())
        Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Preencha o campo " + validar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public boolean validacao() {
    String txtNome = campoNome.getText().toString();
    String txtSenha = campoSenha.getText().toString();
    String txtEmail = campoEmail.getText().toString();

    validar = txtNome.isEmpty() ? "Nome" :
                    txtEmail.isEmpty() ? "Email" :
                    txtSenha.isEmpty() ? "Senha" :
                                             "OK";
    Boolean check = true;
    if(validar.equals("OK"))  check = false;
    return check;
}
```

Comment: Its "the way to use ternary operators", just that nothing more. Define what would be the best in you opinion.

Comment: Its actually recommended *not* to use ternary expressions like that (nested) as some find it somewhat cryptic, although I personally find that usage quite clear. In the end, it's preference - opinion based. What i'm more concerned about is your last 3 lines of that method.. You could simply do `return validar.equals("OK");`

Comment: You could replace the last three lines with `return validar.equals("OK");`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You forgot the `!` not operator in that single-line `return` statement. `equals("OK")` means that `validacao()` returns `false`.

Comment: Is that "the best way to use ternary operator"? *Sure*. --- Is ternary operator the "best way" to write that method? *Nope (my opinion)*. --- Voting to close question as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @Andreas Oops. Yoda condition would work as well. `return !"OK".equals(validar);`

Answer (score 1):

These are the recommendation of using the ternary operator:

- In general try to avoid it, `if()` is easier to read
- If validating more then one option it is better to use `if() else if()` or a `switch() case` for three or more options.